# Ncurses not displaying anything on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: c, ubuntu, ncurses

I'm trying to get into the ncurses library, but it appears that no matter what I code, I get this in ncurses: 
[image: screenshot]

With this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

void main()
{
    WINDOW *vin;
    initscr();
    start_color();
    init_pair(1,COLOR_YELLOW,COLOR_BLUE);
    init_pair(2,COLOR_BLUE,COLOR_YELLOW);
    init_pair(3,COLOR_BLUE,COLOR_WHITE); 
    vin=newwin(12,40,13,0);
    wmove(vin,0,5);
    wprintw(vin,"Hello, World.");
    wbkgd(vin,COLOR_PAIR(1));
    wrefresh(vin);
    getch();
    delwin(vin);
    endwin();
}
```

But, again, this seems to be an issue no matter what code I write whenever I compile with this:

```
gcc main.c -lncurses
```

Is this a bug with the Ubuntu release of ncurses?  Or am I forgetting a library?

Comment: [`void main` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c).

Comment: @melpomene: True, but to be clear that's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Strongly suggest:  just have one window, the default window,  no colors, try the wmove() and wprintw() When you have that working, then add the internal window 'vin' and get that working.  Then add the color.   By developing step by step, you should easily find where your code contains a logic error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `wgetch(vin)` instead of `getch()`. (And, since `wgetch` will call `wrefresh` automatically, you can remove the preceding `wrefresh(vin)`.)

ncurses doesn't let you use overlapping windows. Or, perhaps better said, you can use overlapping windows, but you are responsible for displaying them in the right order.

All of the non-`w` functions -- including `getch` -- work on the main window (returned by `initscr`), which covers the entire screen. If you refresh the main window, you'll overwrite any other windows. So you need to ensure that other windows are refreshed after any refresh of the main window. If you use multiple windows, it is generally best to avoid using the main window; just refresh it once at the beginning and thereafter leave it alone.

Because (w)getch will automatically refresh whatever window it applies to, the call to `getch()` implicitly called `refresh()`; since that came after the call to `wrefresh(vin)`, your subwindow was overwritten.